# Convert linked list in arrayList

Tags: java

I want to convert the `LinkedList` to `arrayList`

```
    Date dataInizio = new Date();
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    int n = combinazioni.size();
    ArrayList<Elemento> temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
    temp.add(combinazioni.get(0));
    queue.add(new Node(0, temp));
    // add all different integers to the queue once.
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (combinazioni.get(i - 1) == combinazioni.get(i)) {
            continue;
        }
        temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
        temp.add(combinazioni.get(i));
        queue.add(new Node(i, temp));
    }
    // do bfs until we have no elements
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node node = queue.remove();
        if (node.lastIndex + 1 < n) {
            Node newNode = new Node(node);
            newNode.lastIndex = node.lastIndex + 1;
            newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(node.lastIndex + 1));
            queue.add(newNode);
        }
        for (int i = node.lastIndex + 2; i < n; ++i) {
            if (combinazioni.get(i - 1) == combinazioni.get(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            // create a copy and add extra integer
            Node newNode = new Node(node);
            newNode.lastIndex = i;
            newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(i));
            queue.add(newNode);
        }
        GestoreRegole gestoreRegole = new GestoreRegole();
        gestoreRegole.esegui(node.currentList);
    }
    Date dataF = new Date();
    long tempo = dataF.getTime() - dataInizio.getTime();
    logger.info("durata genera combinazioni: " + tempo);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)](http://

$SITEURL$/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)]

(http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please explain what it issue, what you are expecting and what you are not able to achieve from your code. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Vorrei convertire il linkedList in arrayList, but I do not know how to do

Comment: Simply iterate over list and add in arraylist

Comment: @Panther why? `ArrayList` has a copy constructor...

Comment: Sorry it just slipped out of my mind. And there are other utility classes to first convert to array then to list. So, I added in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the collections in Java have a constructor that takes a compatible collection and generates a copy of the new type:

```
LinkedList<T> oldList;
ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
LinkedList<T> oldList;
ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
//Optional: newList.ensureCapacity(oldList.size());
newList.addAll(oldList);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
LinkedList<T> oldList;
ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
//Optional: newList.ensureCapacity(oldList.size());
for (T element: oldList) {
  newList.add(element);
}
```

Note that all these have O(n) time and space complexity, as you are effectively creating a new copy of the list content. There is no way around this as LinkedList and ArrayList have different structures. Using one of the approaches above will also speed your code as accessing .get(i) on a linkedList has linear time, while these all use iterators, reducing the initialization cost from O(n^2) as per your code to O(n).

You seem to put a lot on emphasys on removing duplicates. Peraphs a Set collection would be a better option for your use case?

Comment: Hello , then you think how could I proceed to avoid a high consumption of space and memory ?

Comment: In order to answer, I need more context: why exactly do you want an arraylist instead of a linkedlist? What is the broader problem you are trying to solve? I'm sorry, but I can't understand it from your code, so I need you to tell me about it